# Django - Return dict of posts grouped by hash tags

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a search function where the user can search `Post` by `Hash_Tag`. As in each post has a `hash_tags` and I want the the user to be able to do partial search of hash tags and for it to return the results. So for example let's say my `Hash_Tag` table has `[goDawgs, godGiven, goGetEm]` as hash tags stored and the user searches "go" then the results should return something like:

```
{'goDawgs': [list of posts with this hash tag], 'godGiven': [list of posts with this hash tag], 'goGetEm': [list of posts with this hash tag]}
```

As you can see in my `models.py` file below I have the hash tags parsed out and foreign keyed for each post. So it'll have a foreign key reference to hash tags if it's inside the post.

**How can I return a dict of hash tags and all the posts that contain that hash tag?**

view.py

```
from drf_yasg.utils import swagger_auto_schema
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response

from cheers.models import *


@swagger_auto_schema(
    method='get',
    operation_description="icontains search hash_tag table for <input> then retrieves all posts"
                          "with the hash tags"
)
@api_view(['GET'])
def get_search_posts_by_hash_tag(request, input):
    partial_fit_hash_tags_list = list(HashTag.objects.filter(hash_tag__icontain=input).values('hash_tag'))
    filtered_posts = Post.objects.filter(hash_tags__in=partial_fit_hash_tags_list)
    pass
```

model.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField('Created at', auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField('Last updated at', auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="post_creator")
    body = models.CharField(max_length=POST_MAX_LEN, validators=[MinLengthValidator(POST_MIN_LEN)])
    hash_tags = models.ManyToManyField(HashTag)

class HashTag(models.Model):
    hash_tag = models.CharField(max_length=HASH_TAG_MAX_LEN, primary_key=True, validators=[
        MinLengthValidator(HASH_TAG_MIN_LEN)])
    # No update added, because cannot be edited. Can only be added and deleted
```

Answer (score 0):

why not do something like this

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def get_search_posts_by_hash_tag(request, input):
    partial_fit_hash_tags_list = list(HashTag.objects.filter(hash_tag__icontain=input))
    data = {}
    all_posts = Post.objects.all()

    for tag in list(set(partial_fit_hash_tags_list)):
        filtered_posts = all_posts.filter(hash_tags__in=[tag,])
        data[tag.hash_tag] = list(filtered_posts)

    pass
```

Comment: yea that would definitely work. I was just hoping for something a bit more optimized. This seems like it could be very slow, because you are querying for every near similar match. If the hash tab table is huge and there are lots of posts this request could take a long time. I guess that delves more into SEO(search engine optimization), but still something reasonably quick would be nice.

Comment: @user8714896 i have take `all_posts = Post.objects.all()` outside the forloop.that will help i think about performance.look at it.

Comment: isn't that an issue if `Post` table contains a lot of data? I'm not an expert in Django, but I would assume getting all data from a very large table could be very time consuming?